# django making radio select required

Tags: python, django

How can I make the radio select required?
The only way I can think of now is to overwrrite

```
my_list_choices = ( (1,'Yes'),(0,'No'),)

widgets = {
    'my_radio_field' : forms.RadioSelect(choices=my_list_choices),
}
```

edit:
My model is as follows

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, verbose_name='name')
    bool_a = models.BooleanField(blank=False, verbose="bool")
```

I am trying to create a required radio box YES/NO to populate bool_a

Comment: You need to flesh out your question more. Making a radio select required is no different than making anything else required.

Comment: you can change [checkbox apparence with jqueryui](http://devgrow.com/iphone-style-switches/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm much mistaken, when using a form, you can have the form.is_valid() check in your views.

I have a site where this goes down and have a file field as well as radio widget. If I don't select one of them (or both) and press submit, the page reloads and prints out the error (field required).

```
form = myform(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
        # do something awesome
return render_to_response(...)
```

Helpful?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can make any form field required by adding 'required=True' as a parameter on the field object, like so:

```
class MyForm:
    my_answer = django.forms.CharField(max_length=99, required=True)
```

Your question defines a widget, not a form.